# How can I create a screensaver with a password from a Flash/projector file?

Tags: flash, screensaver, projector

I have an projector file/Flash application that I need to turn into an interactive screen saver. I cannot make an actual screen saver of course because screen savers cannot be interacted with.

I need this to be password protected and I need to keep it from being closed. I need to disable any combinations of keys which would cause it to exit.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Is there something like a kiosk mode that I can make the application interactive with, but disable exiting it?

Comment: I need the application to be interactive, ie for there to be buttons the user can click

Comment: If it's interactive, it can't be a screen saver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app that runs after a certain amount of system idle time that requires a password to close?  Not that unusual of a request, and hardly worthy of ridicule.  If it requires you to input a password and click a button to process that input, then it INTERACTIVE, isn't it?

Jeez, lighten up, people.

Just go get this.  Problem solved.
http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/

Flash programming is still PROGRAMMING.  I wish more people would realize that and stop bashing.

Answer (score 2):

Unplug the keyboard and mouse and lock them up in a cabinet?

You can't press exit if there's no exit to press.

---

On a Windows machine, at least, you can't interrupt all shut-down events. For example, `ctrl+alt+del` and pressing and holding the laptop's power button will allow users to exit the application one way or another.

You can't do what you want to do. Moreover, you shouldn't be doing it in the first place because it sounds an awful lot like malware.

Comment: Sometimes, the low-tech solutions are the best.

Comment: Unfortunately, will need it to run on laptops, and will need some degree of interaction (there are buttons the user can click)

Comment: @Tim: Commandeering the user's machine with an application that can't be exited... Are you writing malware?

Comment: @Welbog: Sounds like it to me!

Comment: was for displays on laptops in shops , not a virus :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not Windows that determines when a screensaver ends, it's the screensaver itself. The most common implementation is to exit on any mouse move/click or on any keyboard input. So a screensaver CAN be interacted with if that's how you want it to work. You have control. Doing this from Flash is just a matter of choosing a tool to convert your SWF to a screensaver that supports the options you want. See http://www.northcode.com for another solution.